# Redireccionar a un componente en Angular pasándole un json sin que aparezca como parámetro en la url

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy intentando redireccionar a un componente en Angular 4 y pasarle un json para hacer uso de los datos en el componente destino pero no quiero que aparezca en la url.

Estuve haciendo pruebas con dos opciones: `router.navigate(['/ruta'])` y `router.navigate(['/ruta'],json)`. El resultado que obtuve fue que en la primera opción sí redirige pero no se pasa nada al componente destino y en el segundo caso se redirige al componente y se pasa el json pero no quiero que se muestre la información del json como parámetro en la url.

Estoy abierto a todas las sugerencias que puedan brindarme... Saludos

Comment: Mi sugerencia es que en Javascript no uses la frase *objeto json*, ya que *objeto* no es *json*.

Comment: Gracias @MauricioContreras, saludos

Comment: en https://stackoverflow.com/a/56320227/8957405 veras la forma de hacerlo con un servicio

Answer (score 1):

Te aconsejo que crees un servicio que contenga 2 métodos y una variable con su interface.

```
export interface DatosOcultos{
 idUser:number;
 nombreUser:string;
}


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DatosOcultosService {
  datosOcultos!:DatosOcultos

   recibeDatos(datos:DatosOcultos){
    this.datosOcultos=datos
  }

   devuelveDatos(datos:DatosOcultos){
    return this.datosOcultos
  }
}
```

Luego en el componente que envia los datos puedes injectar el servicio y enviarle los datos

```
constructor(private datosOcultosService: DatosOcultoService, private router:Router){}

// En un método envías al otro componente

navegando(){
this.datosOcultosService.recibeDatos(datosOcultos:DatosOcultos)
this.router.navigate(['/ruta'])
}
```

en el otro componente haces el proceso contrario

```
datosOcultos!:DatosOcultos

constructor(private datosOcultosService: DatosOcultoService){
   this.datosOcultos=this.datosOcultosService.devuelveDatos()
}
```

Espero te sirva